# Modify price while selecting different options in html from Xml Data

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have a page. Containing images, price, options for a product to change colors and few more option. Price is according to the options a user will select. I have the data in xml file.

XML data

```
<product id="100">
   <color>white</color>
   <capacity>16GB</capacity>
   <ram>8GB</ram>
   <price>1999</price>
</product>

<product id="101">
   <color>black</color>
   <capacity>16GB</capacity>
   <ram>8GB</ram>
   <price>1699</price>
</product>
```

HTML

```
<div id="price>1999</div>
<div>
<ul>
   <li>
      <select id="color">
         <option>White</option>
         <option>Black</option>
      </select>
   </li>
   <li>
      <select id="capacity">
         <option>8GB</option>
         <option>16GB</option>
      </select>
   </li>

</ul>

</div>
```

I need to modify the PRICE value in HTML when user change the options like color or capacity etc. Any idea?

Comment: need to be a lot more specific what you mean by `modify price`. Send to server, change some html or???? Also your option tags don't make much sense...no values so no idea how they should work or what your `<select>` 's are even for

Comment: I need to change the price when user change the color from select box or capacity.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not a detailed enough explanation for anyone to properly understand your goals

Comment: creating a demo in jsfiddle.net would also help...along with detailed explanation of goals

Comment: I'm sorry If I would know how to do that I wouldn't have asked this question. I need the idea that how to start.

Let suppose. I have a detail page for Mobile product. White color 8gb has a different price and black 8gb has different. Same for 16 gb, and 32gb and so on for any specs. on the UI, White and black is in a select box and 8gb, 16, 32 is in different select box. When user change the white color to black color from select box. Price should be updated from the xml file according to all the selected specs. 
XML file contains all the data for that Mobile product.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse XML using jQuery only you may loop trough your xml and access the elements like this:
$(xmlDocument).find("node").text("new value")

Comment: How I will parse that what user selected? Like which field is changed. I'm not backend developer but front end. Sorry can you please explain a bit more in detail? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to deal with XML in backend. For example: when user selects a value, make request to server with changed value and some key to find it in XML, then parse XML in server side, change element and save. I can post example for server side (PHP) manipulations with XML.

Comment: Can you please share something that is in working? I can't call a server side request. I need to fetch the price from a list of products that is generated in xml format. As mentioned in above code.